# how to write SQL query to determine the username and email address of the user(s) who logged in most

Tags: sql

How do I determine the email address and user name of the user(s) who authenticate the most? The administrator user should be excluded.

Comment: Do you want to use the internal logs or is there a table? If the former, tag the DBMS. If the latter, tag the DBMS and provide the table structure and sample data.

Comment: 2 upvotes for that question?!? How come?

Comment: @jarth most likely to earn the “first upvote badge” i believe stackoverflow has that?

Comment: @jarlh While this person is clearly new I like their idea. Granted, they need to post some code (e.g. the authentication log table structure from a relevant database). I would like to see how this is pulled off though I'm working on another project right now myself.

Comment: Never mind. But OP could spend some time reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.